# Is there a way/api to get health data from icloud?

Tags: icloud

I'm looking to get step data, I'm aware that there are many ways to access this information with a native app, but I'm wondering if I could access it without access to that phone at all.
I'm asking if there is an API that would allow me to access health data (steps, miles) from an online service like a website with someone's OAuth key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time it appears that although a health kit API exists for native ios apps at this time Apple does not provide a REST API to access this information from the web.... Google does have one in the form of their FIT API though.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the answer.

Has it changed, or still no public API? So, if I am building a fitness app it MUST be native, right?

Comment: @GerardMorera No, unfortunately nothing new. Speculation is that apple with all their privacy stuff won't ever do it either. However that doesn't mean your out of luck. For my WebApp I required people to download the Google fit app which works on both android and iOS and will upload health data to their google account where you can query it via the Google FIT Rest API. Not a perfect suction but it does work. A similiar thing can be done with Garmin.